# If there are $k_1, k_2, \dots, k_n$ divisions by $2$ in a Collatz cycle, then $k_1 + \dots + k_n \geq n$, but can we get a greater lower bound?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, upper-lower-bounds, collatz-conjecture, open-problem

Let $f(x) = |3x + 1|_2(3x + 1)$ be the accelerated Collatz function, where $|3x + 1| = 2^{-\nu_2(3x + 1)}$ is the $2$-adic absolute value.

Clearly for all $x$ odd we have $\nu_2(3x + 1) \geq 1$ so that if the "divisions by $2^{\nu_2(3x_i + 1)}$" in an odd cycle $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ of length $n$ go:

$$
2^{-k_1}, 2^{-k_2}, \dots, 2^{-k_n}
$$

which brings us back to $x_1$ we have the trivial lower bound $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i = k_1 + k_2 + \dots + k_n \geq n$$.  I'm needing better bounds than this. For example, for sufficiently large $n$ (the cycle length) or $x$ (the input to $f$) do we have for example:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n k_i \geq 2n
$$
?

Please provide a link to an article about this, or guide me on how to improve from the trivial bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $k=\sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i$ the number of "even" steps and $n$ the number of "odd" steps you have
$$x_n=\frac{3^n}{2^k}\cdot x_0+\delta_n$$
where $\delta_n$ is the accumulation of "+1" (a sum of power of 2 and 3 over $2^k$)

From here you get
$$x_n>\frac{3^n}{2^k}\cdot x_0$$
and with $x_n=x_0$
$$2^k>3^n$$
$$k>n\cdot \log_2(3)$$
$$k\geq \lceil n\cdot \log_2(3)\rceil$$
Not only this is a lower bound, but this is also believed (not proven) to be an equality.

Comment: Thank you!  Question: does this imply that at least one of the $k_i \gt 1$?   For sufficiently large $n$, that is, and what might that $n$ be around?  Is it unreasonably huge, or feasible to work with?   And can you provide a reference link?

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics, I am not sure what you mean. At least 1 of the $k_i>1$ for $n>0$. If not, we would have $k=n$ which does not fit the inequality. But if you are searching for the the minimum $n$ for which a cycle is possible, you can look at the Simons&Weger 2005 paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228846209_Theoretical_and_computational_bounds_for_m-cycles_of_the_3n_1_problem)

Comment: ...for which a non-trivial cycle is possible...

Comment: I will probably have some questions for you about this post, later on.  Can you go into a little more detail with it?

Comment: Would you be willing to review a paper I'm about to write?  As long as there exist at least $k_2 \geq k_1 \geq 2$.  Then I have proven (to myself only so far) that there exist no nontrivial loops in the positive case.  No other approach does what we did, and it's quite elementary.  Must be an error in it, right?  Well that's where you come in.  Show us that we're wrong.  Let me know and let's meet in chat.  Willing to share prize money :D

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics,, I doubt there is an elementary solution. The proof of the non-existence of a 1-cycle ($a$ "odd" steps followed by $b$ "even steps) already require transcendental number theory (Steiner 1977 using Baker bounds).

Comment: Can you prove that there is no elementary solution for me?  Thank you.

Comment: That's where i said "I doubt". And with 19k rep, you should too

Comment: Yes, I have my doubts, but I have tried about 20 different approaches over that past 3 weeks.  This approach just meshes.  The parts where it could fail, we would need an expert like @Gottfried to show us.   For some strange reason, mathematicians like to brush things under the rug, saying if no one has found the solution (in a certain way) then no one ever will.  There is no proof that mathematicians form a collective brute force engine that indeed checks every possible configuration.

Comment: I gave a reason to doubt, and another would be that those same equations works for cycles (negative cycles, trivial cycle, or positive for 5n+1, 7n+1...), so it would be unlikely you could prove non-cyclicity using simple transformations of those equations since they are "cycle compatible". But you are right, just saying "not possible, someone would have already found it" is not an argument, and I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

*This should not be seen as new answer; it is meant as an explanative comment to the Collag3n's answer, due to OP's additional comments*

The following way to express things with the focus the OP has, is my favorite, and I think that scheme as especially clear.

The one-step formula can be expressed as ("Syracuse style"):
$$ a_{k+1} = { 3a_k+1\over 2^{A_k}} \tag 1$$
$ \qquad \qquad $ *where the $A_k = \nu_2(3 a_k+1)$ .*

*a.1)* For a cycle of 1 step we can write
$$ a_1 = { 3a_1+1\over 2^{A_1}}  \qquad \qquad \implies \quad 
   2^{A_1}=\left( 3+ {1\over a_1} \right) \tag {2.1} $$
*a.2)* For a cycle of 2 step we can write
$$ a_2 = { 3a_1+1\over 2^{A_1}}  \qquad \qquad a_1 = { 3a_2+1\over 2^{A_2}} \\ a_1 \cdot a_2 = { 3a_1+1\over 2^{A_1}}\cdot{ 3a_2+1\over 2^{A_2}} \implies \quad 
   2^{A_1}2^{A_2}=\left( 3+ {1\over a_1} \right)\left( 3+ {1\over a_2} \right) \tag {2.2} $$
*b) Generalizing:* Let's use the symbols $N$ for the (n)umber of $a_k$, and $S$ for the (s)um of the $A_k$, so we have here $N=2$ and we see immediately that in
$$   2^S=\left( 3+ {1\over a_1} \right)\left( 3+ {1\over a_2} \right) \tag 3$$
(assuming all $a_k>0$) the rhs can only be in the interval $\{9 .. 16\}$ = $\{3^N .. 4^N\}$. In the general case for any $N$ and all $a_k>0$ we have thus
$$3^N \lt \text{rhs} \le 4^N = 2^{2N} \tag 4$$

The minimal case $\text{rhs}=3^N$ can only occur as limit, when all $a_k "=" \infty$ and the maximal case $\text{rhs}=2^{2N}$ only if all $a_k=1$ (and by the formula (1) thus ***all*** $A_k=2$). Introducing the lhs in the inequality means
$$3^N \lt 2^S \overset?= \text{rhs} \le 4^N = 2^{2N}$$
The lower bound for $S$ is by this $S \ge \lceil N \cdot \log_2(3) \rceil $ and we have immediately
$$ \lceil N \cdot \log_2(3) \rceil \le S \le 2N \tag 5 $$

The second part of your question, whether for some cycle of -perhaps large- $N$ it can happen, that $S$ exceeds it lower bound, for instance such that $S=\lceil N \cdot \log_2(3) \rceil+1$ is not easily to answer here; this depends on the approximability of $2^S$ and $3^N$ and the distance must be very small relative to $N$ resp $3^N$.

But in your last command you additionally ask, whether it can happen that all $A_k=1$: this can only happen if all $a_k=-1$ such that we have
$$   2^S \overset?=\left( 3+ {1\over -1} \right)^N = (3-1)^N=2^N \\
 \implies S=N \implies \text{all } A_k=1 \tag 6$$
For all other cases where any $a_k \ne -1$ it is necessary that $S>N$ and thus some $A_k>1$
(and for positive $a_k$ the lower bound for the number of $A_k \ge 2$ can be calculated for each $N$ individually) .

---

*Update* The question whether it might be possible, that a cycle sums the $A_k$ to $S=C+1$ where $C=\lceil N \cdot ß\rceil$ and $ß=\log_2(3)$ can be answered by the assumption of a roughly (fractional) mean value of all $a_k$, say "$\alpha$". We look at the generalization of eq (3), but in the better to handle form
$$  {2^S \over 3^N } = (1+\frac1{3a_1})\cdot(1+\frac1{3a_2})\cdots(1+\frac1{3a_N}) = (1+\frac1{3 \alpha})^N \tag 7$$
From this we can get the "mean" value
$$ {2^{S/N} \over 3} = 1+\frac1{3 \alpha}  $$
$\phantom{-----}$ and assuming $S=C+1$
$$
 \alpha = {1 \over 3} \cdot {1\over 2^{(C+1)/N - ß}-1}  \tag 8 
$$
$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad $ *Note: Here the exponent at $2$ can be better rewritten as*
$$ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \small {C+1\over N}-ß = {\lceil N ß \rceil +1 \over N} - ß = { 2+ N ß - \{N ß \} \over N } - ß = { 2 - \{N ß \} \over N }  $$
$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad $ *where the notation $ \{ x \} $ means the fractional part of $x$ and this latter form is better to use when $N$ and thus $C$ become very large numbers.*
We have then that the "mean" values $\alpha$ in most cases are very small, and since the minimal value in the assumed cycle (assumed to be in $a_1$ ) must be smaller than that "mean" value $\alpha$ we have that $a_1 \lt 5$ and thus an a priori forbidden value.
But the convergents of the continued fractions of $ ß=\log_2(3)$ indicate those $N$ where the denominator in eq (8) becomes small and thus $\alpha$ arrives at meaningful values. A short list of this, taken from $N$ and $C$ from that convergents, shows this:

```
        N*1.0         alpha         N/alpha
                5, 2.07381859665, 2.41101126592
               41, 19.2298809957, 2.13209847784
              306, 146.771589110, 2.08487215991
            15601, 7502.13151589, 2.07954232300
            79335, 38151.7019781, 2.07946161997
           190537, 91628.7531413, 2.07944551757
         10781274, 5184696.58678, 2.07944164515
        171928773, 82680262.3510, 2.07944155124
        397573379, 191192380.562, 2.07944154381
       6586818670, 3167590209.94, 2.07944154182
1.37528045312 E11, 66137009651.3, 2.07944154169
5.40930392448 E12, 2.6013253 E12, 2.07944154168
1.15717186888 E13, 5.5648203 E12, 2.07944154168
...
```

Interestingly, the ratio $N/\alpha$ seems to converge to something a bit over $2$, and if $\alpha$ were a sort of *median* then we were lucky here with the disproof: then $N/2$ of the members of a cycle must be smaller than that *median*, and by an average stepping of $a_{k+1}-a_k \sim 3$ we had $a_1 \sim \alpha - 3/2 N \sim N/2-3N/2 \sim - N$. But unfortunately, $\alpha$ is of course not a *median*.

Anyway, I've played with that more precise idea and up to $N=190537$
This shows, that we need ***more*** information to exclude the possibility of a cycle with $S \ge C+1$ . Here is a table to show, if we fill in eq (3), extended up to $N$ parentheses, into the $a_k$ the lowest possible values $a_k \in \{5,7,11,13,...\}$ beginning with $a_1=5$ and look, whether in the rhs would occur a value $2^{S^*}$ equal or larger than $2^{S}=2^{C+1}$. We check for this the value $S^*(N,a_1)=\log_2(\text{rhs})$ and the criterion $crit= S^* - C$.
Table 1:

```
                    a1=5        
     N       C   S*(N,a1) S* - C    
--------------------------------
     2,      4,    3.33, -0.669
     3,      5,    4.95, -0.041
     5,      8,    8.19,  0.192
    10,     16,   16.21,  0.214
    17,     27,   27.38,  0.387
    29,     46,   46.48,  0.488
    41,     65,   65.56,  0.562
```

We show, up to $N=41$, only that $N$ for which the criterion increases, and although we've taken the smallest possible value $5$ into $a_1$ the rhs does not go up to $S^* \ge C+1$. Here $N=41$ is already an entry from the convergents of the cont.frac. and so I show the next $N$ from that convergents only:
Table 2

```
                        a1=5             a1=7
   N       C      S*(N,a1)   S*-C     S*(N,a1)   S*-C 
----------------------------------------------------
    41,     65,     65.56, 0.562      63.82, -1.179
   306,    485,    485.89, 0.895     484.15, -0.848
(  612,    970,    971.01, 1.005   )                 N=612 not in cvgts, but is first case for S*>C+1
 15601,  24727,  24728.52, 1.527   24726.78, -0.218
 79335, 125743, 125744.78, 1.787  125743.04,  0.042
190537, 301994, 301995.92, 1.928  301994.18,  0.183
   ...     ...        ...    ...       ...      ...
```

At least, for $N=15601$ and $a_1=5$, we see that $S^* \ge C+1$, and for $N=190537$ we arrive nearly $S^* = C+2 - \varepsilon$ and of course this shall continue and extend for the following convergents.

Unfortunately, the Q&d-procedure with which I compute this values cannot handle significantly larger $N$ *(a more sophisticated procedure for *N* to arbitrary size is possible if Hurwitz-zeta is employed but I don't have my older studies at hand)* so we have only a tendency. But I've supplied as well the results, when we begin with $a_1=7$ instead of $a_1=5$ in the previous table. This small step invalidates already all found solutions so far: we have $S^* \lt C+1$ for all $N \le 190537$.

Conclusion: after we know, that any cycle cannot have a minimal element $a_1 \lt 2^{64}$ (or so, see wikipedia) we might have an idea how large any $N$ must be to allow $S^* \ge C+1$ at all. (I've not yet checked the idea of @collagen, maybe that arguments suffice to really exclude the possibility of $S* \ge C+1$ at all).

Comment: Indeed :), we just discussed with OP the case $x=-1$ in another post just a moment ago. (I always default to positive integer. Bad habit)

Comment: @Collag3n ;) yes, I had a long cycle to write this down, and in the meantime I also found the other, now self-deleted, question...

Comment: Thank you for this!  I will be going through it later today, tomorrow, or sometime this week.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Since you are some what of a Collatz celebrity around MSE, let me ask you this.  Would you be willing to review a proof of ours that there exist no non-trivial loops in the positive case other than $(1,1), (1,1,1), (1,1,1,1), \dots$?  It's quite elementary other than a basic linear algebraic derivation of the proper formula to use to solve this problem.  The part about $k_i \gt 1$ for at least one $k_i$ is used as a lemma.

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics - thx for the flowers :-) Well, at the moment to read something involved is difficult for me, I'm recovering from some weeks-long labourous disease and am happy that I'm able to involve in a seemingly witched pattern-problem in the coefficients of a powerseries of some fractional iteration function... Anyway, I'm just composing an update to my answer here in the "sandbox", but it seems I've to take some minutes break and come back perhaps in an hour or so. If you're curious enough you might look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13546/1714 meanwhile

Comment: I will check out that sandbox.  I didn't know about that!

Comment: You've lost me at the right side can only be in the interval 9...16.  What do you mean here?  Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you tell me whether you can prove easily enough that there exist at least $2 \leq A_k \leq A_j$ always (in the positive conjecture case)?

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics - your comment conc. rhs in eq (3). If this is unclear ... hmm, just insert values for the $a_k$ and guess : for which $a_k$ can the rhs become smaller than $9$ (=$3^2$)? For which $ a_k$ can the rhs become larger than $16$ (=$4^2)$? Those casas can only happen if $a_k<1$ but that values are forbidden. So the rhs must be between $(3+1/\infty)^2 = 3^2 \lt \text{rhs} \le (3+1/1)^2 = 4^2$ or in short $3^N \lt \text{rhs} \le 4^N$ (with $N=2$ as in the example)

Comment: Is $N$ the number of _odd_ $a_k$ forming a loop of _odd_ numbers or can it be?

Comment: I graphed $\lceil N \log_2(3) \rceil$ using Desmos and apparently for $N \geq 6$ where the formula takes on the value $10$, there is "room for two" of the $A_k$ to be $2$ or more.  I guess you could also have $A_k = 4$ there as well.  Looks like an interesting subproblem to figure out, but with the large known bounds on Collatz, i.e. no nontrivial cycles for $N \leq$ some big number, I think our approach will work!

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics - "N" is the "N"umber-of-steps (of odd $a_k$) in the so-called "Syracuse" notation, which is the notation I and many here in MSE (and you as well if I see correctly?) apply. - - -  Yes, and the subproblem is really interesting; I've experimented much with this, but have no fluently written text so far. I'll refer to this in my "update-under-composition" ;-) (in the sandbox)

Comment: @PenAndPaperMathematics - with $N=612$ and the $a_k \in \{5,7,11,13,...1837\}$ when applied in the appropriate extension of eq (3) I get that the rhs is ***larger*** than $2\cdot 2^C$ where $C=\lceil N \cdot log_2(3)\rceil$ . Of course we know that this set of $a_k$ does not really form a cycle, but this method, applied to sufficients large $N$ and $a_k$ suggests that we ***cannot exclude a cycle*** having $S \ge C+1$ as long as we don't have more useful insight.   I'll insert this result into my upcoming update of my answer much later today.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I'm fine with this current bound :>

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, I explored what you wrote in the sandbox some time ago. If you can show that the smallest  $a_k>\frac{N}{3}$ it would prove $S=C$. I will dig my notes and put it in the sandbox too.

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, I put it in here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts/4669#4669

Comment: The thing "just above 2" is $\log(8)$. This is because $N(2^{1/N}-1)$ tend to $\log(2)$.